# How to restart www-data's session?

Tags: linux, apache

When I add a new group to www-data, I would need to restart the server so that a folder permission within that group will take in effect. Is there a way to make www-data accept the new group it was added to without restarting?

Example, I just created the group "chicken". I've created a folder called "food", whose in the "chicken" group, the permissions on the folder "food" is 775, and finally I added the "chicken" group to www-data. So now when I have a php script that tries to write data into the folder "food", it says something on the lines of access denied.

So after some screwing around, I decide to restart the server and see if it works. And what do you know, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The "session" you're referring to is a full user login. Groups are re-evaulated each time a user logs in, restarting an application from the users point of view does nothing.

Restarting (not reloading) the server performs such a login if started from another user.

```
root              groups for user www-data from /etc/groups: www-data
  |
www-data (groups www-data)
  - server

After adding the chicken group to `www-data``:
root              groups for user www-data from /etc/groups: www-data,chicken
  |
www-data (groups www-data)
  - server
```

If you ask www-data to reload, the login won't be refreshed and hence the groups do not get updated.

```
After logout and login
root              groups for user www-data from /etc/groups: www-data,chicken
  |
www-data (groups www-data,chicken)
  - server
```